# How can I overwrite styles from a css framework while using webpack?

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

I'm using a CSS framework for my app but want to overwrite certain styles. Normally I would do something like:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='link to framework'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='my own stylesheet'>
```

so my stylesheet overwrites any pre-framework-written stylesheet. But react doesn't have a link to `src/app.css` so I'm not sure what to do and couldn't find this in their docs.

*Note: I would like to not use !important because I have found this to be troubling while dealing with site maintenance.

Comment: configure your webpack to load css files and then import it in your component like `import './path/to/app.css'`

Comment: it worked perfectly @ShubhamKhatri

Comment: That's why React works best if you use `style`. Here's [a slide show](https://speakerdeck.com/vjeux/react-css-in-js) that also describes other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

In order to override your framework styles you can configure your webpack if you are using it with `css-loader` like

```
 {
        test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']

    }
```

and import your styles in your App component like

```
import './path/to/app.css'
```

Comment: Webpack is nowhere mentioned in the question, and there is at least browserify.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph kindly have a look at my comment. I posted an answer only after the OP verified that it worked. So that made it clear he was using webpack

Comment: The topic shows up in Google search without any relation to `webpack`, I'll edit the question.