# How to access style element in react component?

Tags: css, reactjs

Need a bit of help with react code.
Suppose a component has style declared in it like

```
          <style>{
            .list-done {
                color:red;
            }
        `}</style>
```

then how do I use this style to style my link tag

```
<li>item1</li>
```

I want to use classnames for this. but how to use it in this case?
I was told to use something like this, but can't find anything in the documentation --> import cx from 'classnames';

Well, I have now declared a variable here

```
const styleItem={color:'red'}
```

How do I conditionally use it?

I am doing it like this

```
style={item.done?styleItem:''}
```

and it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: use `list-done` class in your `li` like `<li class="list-done">item1</li>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a className to your list Item, With react you can add it using className attribute

```
<li className={'list-done'}>item1</li>
```

You might need to load styles in your component. You need to configure `style-loader` with webpack for it.

Check this answer on [how to configure styles with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44622437/how-can-i-overwrite-styles-from-a-css-framework-while-using-webpack/44622881#44622881)

or else write inline styles

```
render() {
   const listStyles = {
       color:red;
   }
   return (
      <li styles={item.done? listStyles: {}}>item1</li>
   )
}
```

Comment: nope. not using webpack here. and i need to put style conditionally too

Comment: you can conditionally add className or styles

Comment: Check the update, style needs an object and not a string

Comment: what if I use className instead. how do I conditionally use it then?

Comment: but where do i put the condition then?

Comment: so, my styles variable is const styleItem = {
       textDecoration:'line-through'
   };

can I use className={item.done?styleItem:''}

Comment: No, className accepts a string, what you want to add is a style, you need to use style attribute instead

Comment: `const styleItem = { textDecoration:'line-through' };

<li style={item.done? styleItem : {}}>Something</li>`

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare styles like this in react. You need to put it as a variable and assign it in style attribute.

```
let styles = { color:red; }
<li style={styles}> item 1 </li>
```

OR

Declare the class outside (may be in some css) and use className attribute to assigne that class

```
<li className='list-done'> item1  </li>
```